# java How to find the max of each row in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, max

i'm writing a function that retrieves the maximum of each row in a 2d array, and returns a 1d array, where each index is relative to the 2d array's column row index.

For example, if I have an 2d array:

```
{1,2,3}
{4,5,6}
{7,8,9}
```

it should return an array of

```
{3,6,9}
```

here is my code so far:

```
double[] rowMaxes(double[][] nums) {
    double [] count = new double [nums.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < nums[0].length; x++){
            for(int n = 0; n < nums.length; n++){
                if(nums[x][n] > count[i]){
                    count[i] = nums[x][n];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my Java 8 one liner solution

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for 3 nested loops. You only need two loops :

```
for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    for(int x = 0; x < nums[0].length; x++){
        if(nums[i][x] > count[i]){
            count[i] = nums[i][x];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that this doesn't work with negative numbers that are the max of the 2d array; only for positives

Comment: @RandyHuang If your array might contain negative numbers, you should initialize all the elements of the `count` array to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @RandyHuang it missing `count[i] = nums[i][0];` in the first loop

Answer (score 0):

You should find row and column length before going in loop.
If you want to consider negative numbers then first define max as minimum negative value.
You can use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double count[][] = {{1,2,3,8},{4,6,5,9},{0,8,9,1}};
        int r = count.length;
        int c= count[0].length;
        double out[] = new double[r];
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
            double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(int x = 0; x < c; x++){
                if(count[i][x] > max)
                    max = count[i][x];
            }
            out[i] = max;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            System.out.println(out[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] getMaxOfRow(int arr[][]){
    int grtr[]=new int[arr.length];
    grtr[0]=arr[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]>grtr[i]){
                grtr[i]=arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return grtr;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackflow, we strongly suggest you to read the guide (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer] about how to answer question.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your code will not work if all values in a row are less than zero.
When you create a new array it will be filled with the default value - it is zero.
Because it you need to add in the first loop `count[i] = nums[i][0]`.

Something like this

```
double[] rowMaxes(double[][] nums) {
    double[] count = new double[nums.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        count[i] = nums[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
            if (count[i] < nums[i][j]) {
                count[i] = nums[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

If you use Java 8, you can replace inner loop with stream and max method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    count[i] = Arrays.stream(nums[i]).max().getAsDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to make it one line, this is the solution with any explicit looping:

```
Arrays.stream(nums).mapToInt((row) -> Arrays.stream(row).max().getAsInt()).max().getAsInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.vikas.array;

public class ArrayGreater_2ndApproach {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int d[][] = { { 1, 5, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            int max = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                if(max<d[i][j]) {
                    max = d[i][j] ;

                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Max number in the row : " + max);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read the questions carefully. The question was about how to get the maximum *per row*. Also, add a comment of your solution to share your thoughts.